# Replace HTML Button with Executed PHP

Tags: php, html, button, web

This is my first post here so thanks in advance for your help.

I have a piece of `PHP` code for getting an airport METAR and displaying it. The code 'metar.php' is as follows:

```
<?php

$location = "EGLL";

get_metar($location);

function get_metar($location) {
$fileName = "http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/stations/$location.TXT";
    $metar = '';
    $fileData = @file($fileName) or die('METAR not available');
    if ($fileData != false) {
            list($i, $date) = each($fileData); 

            $utc = strtotime(trim($date));
            $time = date("D, F jS Y g:i A",$utc);

            while (list($i, $line) = each($fileData)) {
                    $metar .= ' ' . trim($line);
                    }
            $metar = trim(str_replace('  ', ' ', $metar));
            }

    echo "<div style=\"color: white;\">METAR FOR $location (Issued: $time UTC):<br>$metar</div>";
    }
 ?>
```

Currently, there are buttons on the frontpage of my website that redirect to website.com/metar.php when the button is clicked. The code is as follows:

```
 <li><button type="submit" style="height: 40px;" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.location.href = '/heathrow.php'"/>METAR At London Heathrow</button></li>
```

I would appreciate it if someone can tell me how to change this code so that the button is replaced by the output of metar.php when it is clicked rather than having to redirect to website.com/metar.php when the button is clicked.

I hope that made sense 
Thank you very much again in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Please read the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. You'll notice you're supposed to show us what you've tried which is not the case for the moment. As it is sometimes hard to even know where to start, here are some tips : you will need to use javascript to do that. More specificically, to request the page you will need to use AJAX. That said, you seem to also have the hands on that metar.php page, so you might just aswell get this data server-side on your frontpage, place it somewhere in your HTML but hide it, and show it upon button click.

Comment: Sorry. As I said it is my first question on the site. Would you mind posting an answer to show how I might be able to hide it and show it when the button is clicked? Thanks again.

Comment: You can perform an AJAX request in order to accomplish such. In any case, since PHP is a server-side language, you literally have no way to edit your HTML without refreshing the page (using PHP). You can, however, accomplish such by using javascript and, for an even simpler usage, I would go with jQuery for such a case in order to extremely simplify the whole code. Please look at an example of http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ and configure your current index to perform an AJAX request to your metar.php script that is supposed, at this point, to return a value.

Comment: Not a big deal, we all have to start somewhere, but yes I would mind posting the code as this is something you can very easily find on the internet, were you using a javascript framework (jQuery for example) or Plain javascript. In both cases, we're talking about a 1 line code.

Comment: So would this work?

`<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#container-id-to-load-into').load('metar.php);
 });
</script>`

Comment: @TheoBearman: since you're using `btn btn-primary` as classes, I suppose that you're using bootstrap. In such a case, unless you've made your own "package", you should already have included jQuery. Also, No, .load won't work.

Comment: How would I implement what @MažvydasTadaravičius has said into the code for the button on my index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using AJAX. Code bellow shows how it can be done using jQuery.

```
<div id="dectinationDivId" style="color: white;"></div>

<button id="buttonId" style="height: 40px;" class="btn btn-primary">METAR At London Heathrow</button>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#buttonId').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/heathrow.php",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#dectinationDivId').html(data);
                $('#buttonId').hide();
            },
            error: function(jqXHR) {
                alert(jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

For multiple buttons there is a better, more generic, approach which makes it easier to maintain code (add and remove buttons, in this case).

HTML/JS:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var metarButtons = $('.getMetarButtons');
        metarButtons.click(function(){
            var clickedButton = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/metarData.php",
                data: { location: clickedButton.attr('data-location') },
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(data) {

                    $('#outputDiv').hide('slow', function() {
                        $(this).remove();
                    });

                    metarButtons.show('slow');

                    var outputElement = $('<div id="outputDiv" style="color: white;">' + data + '</div>');
                    outputElement.hide();
                    outputElement.insertAfter(clickedButton);

                    clickedButton.hide('slow', function() {
                        outputElement.show('slow');
                    });
                },
                error: function(jqXHR) {
                    alert(jqXHR.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<button style="height: 40px;" class="btn btn-primary getMetarButtons" data-location = "LLBG">METAR At Tel Aviv Ben Gurion</button>
<button style="height: 40px;" class="btn btn-primary getMetarButtons" data-location = "EGLL">METAR At London Heathrow</button>
<button style="height: 40px;" class="btn btn-primary getMetarButtons" data-location = "EGGW">METAR At London Luton</button>
<button style="height: 40px;" class="btn btn-primary getMetarButtons" data-location = "KJFK">METAR At New York John F. Kennedy</button>
```

PHP (metarData.php):

```
<?php
    $location = $_POST["location"];

    get_metar($location);

    function get_metar($location) {
    $fileName = "http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/stations/$location.TXT";
        $metar = '';
        $fileData = @file($fileName) or die('METAR not available');
        if ($fileData != false) {
            list($i, $date) = each($fileData); 

                $utc = strtotime(trim($date));
                $time = date("D, F jS Y g:i A",$utc);

                while (list($i, $line) = each($fileData)) {
                    $metar .= ' ' . trim($line);
                }
            $metar = trim(str_replace('  ', ' ', $metar));
        }

        echo "METAR FOR $location (Issued: $time UTC):<br>$metar";
    }
?>
```

Comment: @MažvydasTadaravičius Well, half works. See the [website](http://theobearman.com) and try clicking the buttons. It seems only the top one works and then loads one of the four defined stations at random when it is clicked.

Comment: @TheoBearman - When selecting element by _id_, if there are multiple elements with the same _id_, only first one gets selected. In Your case, because You have 4 buttons, 4 unique _ids_ have to be used. Or with some modification to PHP, JS and HTML, You can have 4 buttons with same class and _location_ attribute which would get passed to PHP. This way, only one _AJAX_ function would have to be declared.

Comment: @MažvydasTadaravičius I understand. I am currently in a lesson but I will assign each button a unique _ID_ when I can. That should make it work yes?

Comment: @MažvydasTadaravičius Is it the buttonID or DivID I need to make unique or both?

Comment: @TheoBearman - If You use _Copy/Paste_ approach, then both _ids_ have to be unique, as well as JS code _Copy/Pasted_ and changed accordingly. As I've mentioned previously, there is a better, more generic, approach. I've updated my answer to show it.

Comment: @MažvydasTadaravičius In the PHP the $location value changes for each airport. For example, Heathrow is _EGLL_ but Luton is _EGGW_ where do I define that?

Comment: @TheoBearman - If You take a look at my answer, I've added a better way of doing it. Then You use HTML _data-*_ attribute to define different locations for different buttons. Then with jQuery, You post value of _data-*_ to PHP, which in turn return text relevant to selected location. If You give me all 4 location codes, I can put them to my answer.

Comment: @MažvydasTadaravičius _EGLL_, _EGGW_, _KJFK_, _LLBG_. Thanks again in advance!

Comment: @TheoBearman - Changes done. Take a look at _data-location_ attribute of HTML Buttons. Try this code and let me know if You have any problems.

Comment: It is working however I have a new problem.

Scenario: 

I press the button for _METAR at Tel Aviv Ben Gurion_
The METAR appears and the button for Tel Aviv disappears (that is what I want)
I then press the button for _METAR at London Heathrow_ and the METAR appears in place of the button (again correct).
However - The METAR for Tel Aviv does not disappear and is then replaced by the Tel Aviv button when I press the Heathrow one.

See [here](http://www.theobearman.com) to see what I'm talking about. Thanks again!

Comment: @TheoBearman - Updated code to do what You want. All You have to do is manipulate jQuery objects to achieve different results. jQuery has extensive documentation and every method.

Comment: PEFECT! Exactly what I wanted! Thank you so much. I owe you a drink!